# static global std::unique_ptr disappears

Tags: c++, static

I probably misunderstood how static objects work. Suppose following

common.hpp

```
struct common {};
static std::unique_ptr<common> global_ptr;
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "common.hpp"
void bar();
int main()
{
    global_ptr = std::make_unique<common>();
    bar();
}
```

bar.cpp

```
#include "common.hpp"
void bar()
{
    *global_ptr; // crashes, because global_ptr is empty
}
```

I am able to debug such situation, and `&global_ptr` is different in `main()` and `bar()`, why is that? `global_ptr` is definitely initialized in `main()`, I can use it without problem, but why `global_ptr` in `bar()` seems unitialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` variable at global and namespace scope means [internal linkage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

> The name can be referred to from all scopes in the current translation unit.

It means `global_ptr` in different translation unit are different objects. The static variable is not visible outside of its own translation unit. There might be many objects with the name `global_ptr`, but only one per translation unit.

If you just want a global variable, you could declare it in `common.hpp` as:

```
extern std::unique_ptr<common> global_ptr;
```

and define it in the cpp file (might be `common.cpp`):

```
std::unique_ptr<common> global_ptr;
```

Comment: Is it OK to define it as global in one translation unit and `extern` in others?

Comment: @Zereges It doesn't make sense. The static variable is only visible in its own translation unit.

Comment: I meant, not static (just in global scope) and `extern` in header file.

Comment: @Zereges Non-static and extern would be fine. Note it'll be just declaration, you need to add the definition in cpp file (might be `common.cpp`).

Answer (score 2):

Globals behave like your intended behavior without the static keyword.
Static means that the global is actually local to the translation unit.
Your confusion comes from the fact that static means different things in global scope and in function scope.